# filling in missing "holes" in a dataset

Tags: r, plyr

I have a dataset like this:

```
Patient_ID Lab_No Discharge_Date
P0001      L001   2010-01-01
P0001      L002   
P0001      L003   
P0001      L004
```

I have some lab data that from the same patient, some lab data does not carry the discharge date that it should have. And I need to place the missing discharge date into them, currently I am using the following code:

```
temp <- ddply(temp,
             c("Patient_ID"),
             function(df)
               {
                df[,"Discharge_Date"] <- unique(df[!is.na(df[,"Discharge_Date"]),"Discharge_Date"])
                data.frame(df)
               },
             .progress="text"
             )
```

But this is quite slow (the dataset has 92528 rows with 70527 unique patient_id), how can I speed it up? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

merge, should be much faster.

```
temp2 <- na.omit(temp) ## create unique discharge date x patient ID list
temp3 <- merge(temp[1:2], temp2[c(1,3)], by="Patient_ID") ## merge
```

Comment: thanks! you saved my day, am checking on the data again to see if I have missed anything there. Thanks again!